# Protecting polynom package against Czech babel option

Tags: babel, polynom

I encountered a problem when I try to typeset text with the babel library for the Czech language and using the [polynom](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polynom) library. The correct polynom division looks like below.

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polynom}

\listfiles
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \polylongdiv[style=C,div=:]{x^3+4x^2-x+2}{x^2+x-3}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

and the wrong output is:
[image]

I don't know, how can protect the command `\polylongdiv`. The magic word `\protect\polylongdiv` leads to a compile error. The command `\shorthandoff{-}` doesn't work. So I exhausted all the tricks.

Comment: `\shorthandoff{-}`  works for me, if used after \begin{document}.

Comment: The problem is the same with `\usepackage[slovak]{babel}` and the solution is good also in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch `\polylongdiv` to locally set `\shorthandoff{-}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\polylongdiv}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\shorthandoff{-}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\polylongdiv[style=C,div=:]{x^3+4x^2-x+2}{x^2+x-3}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]